# Spatie laravel-permissions Giving Error of Argument 1 Passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working with the Spatie laravel-permissions package. When I create my role I want to assign permissions to roles but it's returning the error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\GuardDoesNotMatch::create() must be of
>   the type string, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasPermissions.php
>   on line 505

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate name and permissions field
    $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:' . config('permission.table_names.roles') . '|max:10',
        ]
    );

    $name = $request['name'];
    $role = new Role();
    $role->name = $name;

    $permissions = $request->permissions;
    $role->save();

    // Looping thru selected permissions
    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        $p = Permission::where('id', '=', $permission)->firstOrFail();
        // Fetch the newly created role and assign permission
        $role = Role::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
        $role->givePermissionTo($p);
    }

    return redirect()->route('roles.index')
        ->with('flash_message',  'Role' . $role->name . ' added!');
}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-4'>
    <h1><i class='fa fa-key'></i> Add Role</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="{{action('RoleController@store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin:5%;">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" id="name" name="name"
                   placeholder="Enter your Role Name"/>
        </div>

        <h5><b>Assign Permissions</b></h5>
        <div class="form-check">
            @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                    {{$permission->name}}
                </label>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin:5%;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">Add Role</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

This is the screenshot
[image: dd($request->permissions);]

Comment: When you do `dd($request->permissions)`, what do you get returned?

Comment: @PeterSowah its returning an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

$guard_name of the Model is different or NULL from the $Request make sure both are in the same Guard 'web' / 'api'

// Solution by: @VardanaBhanot in comments

**RoleController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate role 'name' and make sure that's unique within 'roles' table
    // upon creating a role we want to make sure that it's not an empty role
    // so permissions are required
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:roles|max:10',
        'permissions' => 'required'
      ]);

    // create the role by given name and assign it to @var $role
    $role = Role::create(['name' => $request['name']]);

  // since we are using Validator to make sure "permissions" exists 
  // we can skip the "isset($request['permission'])" call.
  foreach($request['permissions'] as $permission)
  {
    if($p = Permission::where('id', '=', $permission)->first())
    {
      $role->givePermissionTo($p);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post what's inside of $request (dd($request->all());)

Comment: Can you explain how a single assignment of a variable solves the problem?

Comment: Can you Post your Permissions Model & Roles Model. The Code above works just fine within my dev environment.

Comment: Thanks @Julian for your support I fixed the error actually the error is the gaurd_name was set to null

Comment: @VardanaBhanot that's why i asked for your Models :P i'll  - update the Answer

Comment: I am really sorry about that @Julian